# Using both POI and Routes layers for ArcGIS Address Locator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geocoding, address

I want to create an address locator in ArcGIS. I have a POI Layer and Routes Layer. The Address locator should be use both Street names and POI distance. For example "X" Ave near the "Y" Gas station.I Created an address Locator with One Range Style and another Address Locator for POI with Single Field Style. But i want to merge these locators in one locator
Is it possible to use POI layer to show the proximity of a POI for users in Address Locator?